# What is the reason for this discrepancy between confidence level and probability?

Tags: r, probability, confidence-interval, binomial-distribution

I ran the following R code:

```
library(Hmisc)
binconf(x=1, n=70)
#   PointEst         Lower      Upper
# 0.01428571  0.0007327613 0.07658187
```

Which is the confidence interval with 95% confidence.

But when I try to find the probability:

```
pbinom(0.07658187*70, 70, 1/70)-pbinom(0.0007327613*70, 70, 1/70))
# [1] 0.634254
```

It gives `0.63`; that is, 63%.  Why is this so far from 95%?

Comment: Welcome to our site!  I have taken the liberty of writing in the question I believe you are trying to ask.  Please check it over to make sure my interpretation is correct.  Consider taking a minute or two to review our [help] for information on formulating answerable questions.  You might also enjoy reviewing some of our [threads on confidence intervals](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/confidence-interval?sort=votes&pageSize=15), because your question appears to originate from a misunderstanding of what a confidence interval is (which in many ways makes it a good question!).

Comment: Although asked in terms of R, I think this is actually a question prompted by an important statistical misunderstanding. I am voting to leave open.

Comment: What package is `binconf` in? It's not in the normal R distribution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It isn't clear that the output is incorrect.  The problem is that there is a confusion about the distribution and the interval you are referring to.  Specifically, the `binconf()` function pertains to the *sampling* distribution of the proportion.  The code you used to double check that is based on a misunderstanding.

In general, there are three distributions that we are working with or thinking about when we analyze data.  These are the population distribution, which is ultimately what we care about; the sample distribution, which is what we really have access to; and the sampling distribution, which is what allows us to connect the former two.

Since the type of data you have come from Bernoulli trials, your data are distributed as a binomial, and the parameter that governs the behavior of a binomial is the probability of 'success'.  From your sample data, you calculated a mean / the proportion of successes (i.e., `1/70 = 0.01428571`).  That can be used as an estimate of the binomial probability.  Just having a point estimate isn't enough for most people.  It's nice to have a sense of the precision of the estimate.  The confidence interval can give you a sense of how close your estimate might be to the true probability.  It is *not* the middle 95% of the population distribution, though.  Instead it is the middle 95% of the estimated sampling distribution.

To calculate an interval covering the middle 95% of the population (if you wanted that for some reason), it would be:

```
qbinom(c(.025, .975), size=70, prob=0.01428571)
# [1] 0 3
```

That is, approximately 95% of values drawn from ${\rm binom}(0.014, 70)$ will fall within the interval $[0, 3]$.

The function you used (e.g., `pbinom(0.07658187*70, 70, 1/70)`), isn't really appropriate here.  It has to do with the proportion of the ${\rm binom}(0.014, 70)$ distribution you have passed through when you reach the quantile `5.360731`.  This isn't very clearly related to anything you are trying to do.